# How to apply click event on digit in html?

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

In my website user enters a number.When user click on any number then program should search for all records in database where key="user selected number".

My problem is how to apply click event on digit and how to get that particular number is clicked ?

Here is my numberch.jsp code

```
      <% 
 out.print("<div class=bs-docs-example style=width:400px>");

 out.print("<h3><b>Enter the list of Property Ids for Delete</b></h3>
<form action=numberch.jsp method=post><input type=text name=number><br/><br/><br/>    <input type=submit name=go value=Send></form>");
out.print("</div>");
String numbers = request.getParameter("number"); 
PreparedStatement ps=null;
Connection con = null;
DBManager db = new DBManager();
con=db.createConnection(); 
Statement statement = null;
//statement = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=null;      

    if(numbers!=null)
    {


        if(numbers.length()>0)
        {
            String tokens[]=numbers.split("[,]");


            out.print("<div class=list>");

            out.print("<div class=bs-docs-example style=top:-420px;left:600px;width:400px;height:145px;overflow:auto>");

            out.print("<ul style=list-style:none>");
            out.print("<table>");
            out.print("<th> Property Ids for Delete</th>");
                for(int i=0;i<tokens.length;i++)
                    {

                    ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into property_delete(property_id) values(?)");
                    ps.setString(1,tokens[i]);
                    ps.executeUpdate(); 


                        out.print("<tr><td><hr>");
                        out.print("<li>");  out.print(tokens[i]); out.print("</li>");
                        out.print("</td></tr>");    

                        out.print("<input type=\"hidden\"  name=\"delete_numbers\" value=\"delete\">");
                    }
                out.print("</table></ul>");

                out.print("</div></div>");
        }
    }



 %>
```

In above code list present in 2nd if block where tokens[i] prints that numbers..
I want to apply click event on that numbers...

screenn

[image]

Comment: Are using 3rd part library like jQuery or just plain old JS?

Comment: Maybe you already do, but use single `'` or double quotes `\"`: `style='top:-420px;left:600px;width:400px;height:145px;overflow:auto'`.

Comment: I was just add my screen in my question,in which user creates list(right hand side) by adding numbers in text box separated by comma(left side).Now when user click on any number from list(right side) it will show all details from database, whose id is selected number.So I would I know which number is clicked,how i get value of clicked number in jsp so i could search in database.

Comment: @Thihara see the screen so u get my problem very well

Comment: @RupeshNerkar : So if you click on number, all details with that number will be shown on new page.. right?

Comment: @RupeshNerkar : Also to update, what you want to achieve will not be done by JS. JS is client side. you have to handle it in JSP.

Comment: @FahimParkar no not on new page, I want all details just below the text box as you can see it in image uploaded by me.

Comment: @RupeshNerkar : You will need to use Ajax for that then,.. also if you would have used JSF, it would have been easier.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21000/discussion-between-rupesh-nerkar-and-fahim-parkar)

Comment: I suggest you take a look at jQuery selectable... Personally for something like this I'll use that or jQGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
out.print("<a href='#no_target' onclick='yourJSFunction(\""+tokens[i]+"\")'>" + tokens[i] +"</a>");
```

instead of

```
out.print(tokens[i]);
```

Comment: @Rupesh: Yeah, so whats the issue? In yourJSFunction(id) you can make an AJAX call to fetch the data from DB and display it in you page.